# Loop over a column in a Dataframe and then replace with a list of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has "?" in the data.[This is a pic of said df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbhro.jpg) I had to calculate the values that would go where these ? are in another part of the assignment.[values that need to be added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsVFP.jpg). I need a way to add these values into a SINGLE column in a pandas dataframe. I need it to add the data in the order that it is in the first picture (even though the indices obviously do not match) in order of the "?" down the larger column in the main dataframe.

Comment: Look at using `pd.wide_to_long`.

Comment: I don't think it will do exactly what I need, because I need to fully replace the data. The full dataset is 8,000 rows I need 1 column, 2,000 "?" replaced with the numbers in the data frame I created

Comment: Look at `pd.DataFrame.melt` and see that works.